# In storyboard, can you edit the layout for just one device?

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, storyboard, size-classes

Using storyboard, I know you can vary the layout based on its size class (regular versus compact), but is there a way to edit the layout for just ONE particular screen size?

For example, let's say my app looks great on every device EXCEPT the iPhone SE, which is just too dang small for the layout to look good. Is there some way to have a unique layout for just this device??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not via the storyboard. Sorry about that. If you really wanted to rearrange the screen based on something that fine-grained (device type, screen size, etc.) you'd have to do it in code.

Comment: Shoot...that's unfortunate. Definitely should be a feature IMO. Thanks for the response